# MS Access Create column with Double data type

Tags: ms-access

I Want to Create a table which contains the column of type `DOUBLE` real Number. I Can find the datatype `Number` in the Table Design view, But no Double or single, Float.. how to achieve..?

also i need the SQL Query for creating table with `Double` column and DATA types list which can be used in QUERY to create table. In the design view there is limited no. of Data types..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following Access SQL [CREATE TABLE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb177893%28v=office.12%29.aspx) statement creates a table with a field of type "Double"

```
CREATE TABLE Gord (dblField DOUBLE)
```

Look here for a list of the various Access field type names and constants:

http://allenbrowne.com/ser-49.html

Answer (score 1):

You can of course create columns of type "Double" (and others) with the table designer, too.

Simply select "number" as datatype and then look at the lower half of the table designer where you can specify the exact type (which is by default "Long Integer" if you have chosen "Number" as basic data type).

In fact Access also uses a single list of datatypes as any other database, but the table designer "groups" such datatypes into basic data types.

Answer (score 1):

1. Right Click on your table.
2. Click on Design View.
3. Select dblField's DataType field.
4. Now as Bitsqueezer mentioned in the above answer, look at the lower half of the table designer, find 'Field Size' and changes from default 'Long Integer' to 'Double'.